# What parameter is the Wilcoxon 2-sample statistic estimating?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

I'm reading about the Wilcoxon 2-sample statistic. They say that this is an estimator for the following parameter:
$$\theta(F,G) = \int F \, dG = P(X \leq Y)$$
where $F$ and $G$ are continuous distribution functions for the random variables $X$ and $Y$.

How does $\theta$ give us $P(X \leq Y)$? Asked another way: why does $\int F \, dG $ imply $P(X \leq Y)$?

[For context this is the first example of 5.1.3 in Serfling (1980)]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to know about the continuous version of Law of Total Probability, and the Riemann–Stieltjes Integral, to arrive that

$$ \begin{align}
\Pr\{X \leq Y\} &= \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\Pr\{X\leq Y \mid Y=y\}dG(y) \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\Pr\{X\leq y\}dG(y) \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}F(y)dG(y)
\end{align}$$